# Can't decode result from urlopen

Tags: python, urllib

I have the following code in Python3

```
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.okcoin.cn/api/v1/trades.do?since=0")
a = f.read()  # there is data here
print(a.decode())  # error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I can get a readable result for https://www.okcoin.cn/api/v1/trades.do?since=0 in a browser. The browser confirms the encoding is UTF-8.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to use `requests` module?

```
import requests
f = requests.get("https://www.okcoin.cn/api/v1/trades.do?since=0")
a = f.text
print(a)
```

Works fine for me :)

Comment: `requests` library automatically handles compressed data, see this [faq](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/faq/#encoded-data)

Answer (score 4):

Downloading the data with `wget` reveals that the data is actually
compressed with gzip. So you need to decompress it first. There’s a
`gzip` module that should be useful.

Edit: try this.

```
import urllib.request
import gzip

f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.okcoin.cn/api/v1/trades.do?since=0")
a = f.read()  # there is data here

uncompressed = gzip.decompress(a)
print(uncompressed.decode())
```

Comment: Thanks !This answer is more informative but @YuvalPruss provided a more practical solution (simplier)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned on my comment @Yuval Pruss's answer, `requests` modules handle compressed data implicitly, [`urllib3`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#urllib3) as well does the same-thing as it has Support for gzip and deflate encoding. Here is a demonstration:

```
>>> import urllib3
>>> http = urllib3.PoolManager()
>>> r = http.request("https://www.okcoin.cn/api/v1/trades.do?since=0")
>>> r.headers['content-encoding']
'gzip'
>>>
>>> import json
>>> if r.status == 200:
        json_data = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
        print(json_data[0])
{'date_ms': 1489842827000, 'tid': 7368887285, 'date': 1489842827, 'price': '7236.01', 'amount': '1.081', 'type': 'sell'}
```